# Three20 autorotate in iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, three20, autorotate, ttnavigator

I try to get autorotate work in iOS6. I've already read about it and the problem is, that I can't set a rootviewcontroller for the window. I've tried it with:
`self.window.rootViewController = [[TTNavigator navigator] rootViewController];`
but the App crashes with unrecognized selector...
In iOS5 the autorotation worked fine with the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial worked for me: http://www.goodnewtiger.com/llf/cegeek/?p=61
I had to change the TTNavigationController and set the viewcontroller in the app delegate.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setRootViewController:[[TTNavigator navigator] rootViewController]];

Answer (score 1):

Autorotation changed with iOS6. Yes in iOS5 you used `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`. You'll still need that to support iOS5, but to support iOS6, drop in the new method below.

I think this is what you're after.

```
#pragma mark - View Orientation
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
// For iOS6

NSUInteger orientation = 0;

orientation |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
orientation |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
orientation |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
orientation |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;

return orientation;
}
```

Then comment out, or remove the lines that you don't want to support. You could return that on one line bitwise 'OR'ing the desired orientations. There are two others available:

`UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll` and `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that doesn't work. I think it has something todo with Three20 in combination with iOS6.

Comment: @Eragonio Since its a custom control, could it be that the ios6 version of rotate hasn't yet been implemented yet? Short of the other answers here and in other SO threads, could you not simply implement that yourself? Sorry I have no experience with Three20 yet.

Comment: And I just realised the other answer here IS your answer. Glad you got it